# Categories column on the basis of distinct value in Spark Dataframe

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In my source data, I don't have any category column on which I can group data.

So, I want to add a new custom category column in Spark dataframe on the basis of another column say("QNAME") distinct value. Which I want to use in group By to Pivot.

Till now, I have no idea... how to get this.

Let's say I have below source dataframe

```
   Qname    b   c   d
    SPT     1   10  555
    MTK     2   20  556
    NKP     3   30  557
    LKM     4   40  558
    SPT     5   50  559     
    MTK     7   70  561
    QRS     6   60  560
    NKP     7   70  561
    SPT     5   50  559
    LKM     7   70  561
    QRS     7   70  561
    MTK     7   70  561
    NKP     7   70  561
```

So, on the basis of column("QNAME") values, I want to categories on distinct value combination.
For example, ditinct values are (SPT,MTK,NKP,LKM,QRS)... So for first ocuurence of this value will maked as "aaa", then 2nd occurence will marked as "bbb" and so on.

So, below is the expected output.

```
  Category         Qname    b   c   d
    "aaa"           SPT     1   10  555
    "aaa"           MTK     2   20  556
    "aaa"           NKP     3   30  557
    "aaa"           LKM     4   40  558
    "bbb"           SPT     5   50  559     
    "bbb"           MTK     7   70  561
    "aaa"           QRS     6   60  560
    "bbb"           NKP     7   70  561
    "ccc"           SPT     5   50  559
    "bbb"           LKM     7   70  561
    "bbb"           QRS     7   70  561
    "ccc"           MTK     7   70  561
    "ccc"           NKP     7   70  561
```

I am using Scala and Spark to do this. 
Any help or suggestion is appreciated to crack this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are there going to be a maximum of 26 occurrences of each distinct value of QNAME? Otherwise, you will run out of letters (“aaa”, “bbb”, ..., “zzz”)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Task can be completed with Window function "row_number()". If take into account
Jonathan Myers comment, better use just numbers instead of characters:

```
val df = Seq(
  ("SPT", 1, 10, 555),
  ("MTK", 2, 20, 556),
  ("NKP", 3, 30, 557),
  ("LKM", 4, 40, 558),
  ("SPT", 5, 50, 559),
  ("MTK", 7, 70, 561),
  ("QRS", 6, 60, 560),
  ("NKP", 7, 70, 561),
  ("SPT", 5, 50, 559),
  ("LKM", 7, 70, 561),
  ("QRS", 7, 70, 561),
  ("MTK", 7, 70, 561),
  ("NKP", 7, 70, 561)
).toDF(
  "Qname", "b", "c", "d"
)

// action
val categoryWindow = Window.partitionBy($"Qname").orderBy("c")
val result = df.withColumn("Category", row_number().over(categoryWindow))
```

Result:

```
+--------+-----+---+---+---+
|Category|Qname|b  |c  |d  |
+--------+-----+---+---+---+
|1       |SPT  |1  |10 |555|
|1       |NKP  |3  |30 |557|
|1       |QRS  |6  |60 |560|
|1       |LKM  |4  |40 |558|
|1       |MTK  |2  |20 |556|
|2       |NKP  |7  |70 |561|
|2       |LKM  |7  |70 |561|
|2       |QRS  |7  |70 |561|
|2       |SPT  |5  |50 |559|
|2       |MTK  |7  |70 |561|
|3       |NKP  |7  |70 |561|
|3       |MTK  |7  |70 |561|
|3       |SPT  |5  |50 |559|
+--------+-----+---+---+---+
```